# Is there a way to get a template type from an integer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, crtp

I tried to do the following

```
template <typename T>
constexpr int some_constexpr_function() {/*some macro magic*/}

struct Base
{
    template <int N>
    struct IntToType;
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{
    template<>
    struct IntToType<some_constexpr_function<T>()>
    { using type = T; };
};
```

so I could do this

```
struct Example : Derived<Example> {}
//...
void do_something()
{
    constexpr int n = some_constexpr_function<Example>();
    Base::IntToType<n>::type example_object;
}
```

Obviously this code won't compile, but I was wondering if there was some way to get the desired result.
"some_constexpr_function" manages to give different results depending on T thanks to some macro magic.
I can't manually specialize IntToType for every possible result.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you want to do this?  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: So you map types to integers somehow in `some_constexpr_function` and you want to build a reverse map automatically, amirite?

Comment: I am aware my problem can be solved in much simpler ways; I'm trying to implement an ECS using a bus: Entity.AddComponent<Example>() would send a message to a bus that would dispatch it to every interested listener (like a ComponentManager). I'm still interested in mapping types to values and viceversa and I've seen people manually do it with compile-time maps, but then again they manually specify every entry while I would need to build it automatically. So yeah I need a reverse map or some other way to accomplish this (then again I don't want to just solve the ECS problem)

Comment: I cannot see how mapping types to values would help you implement an ECS, unless you are interested in a compile-time-only ECS. Anyway, you cannot do that without language magic, and the language currently has no such magic. Maybe in 2029 when they make `typeid(type)` is `constexpr` and create a magical `template<std::type_info> class reverse_typeid`.

Answer (score 3):

Stateful metaprogramming tricks have been found in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) at various points, allowing for a count (in each compilation unit) of the number of times a given template was instantiated with distinct types.

Even when such tricks where legal under the current wording of the standard, the C++ committee has treated them like bugs and worked to remove them from being legal under the standard.  They want template metaprogramming to be [pure](/questions/tagged/pure) for various reasons, including making it easier for compilers to memoize it and similar.

As the space of types is unbounded in size and the space of `constexpr int`s is not, there is no function that injectively maps a type to a `constexpr int`.  In theory a high quality hash could be used, but the amount of information available to a C++ constexpr template program about a type (without the reflection TS) isn't going to be large enough to make a meaningful hash.

It is possible to make **values** which can be mapped back to types.  The simplest one is:

```
template<class T> struct tag_t { using type=T; };
template<class T> constexpr tag_t<T> tag = {};
```

it is sometimes useful to be able to pass around types and the like as values, and this permits that to work; in this case, the type of the value carries with it the payload.

This isn't quite what you asked for, but it might solve the underlying problem you are trying to address.

Given a bundle of of types `Ts...` , you can even create `std::variant<tag_t<Ts>...>`, which can be a `constexpr` variable whose value is the index into the `tag_t` corresponding to a type.  Here we **define** the map between type and index by the order of `Ts...` elements.

```
template<class...Ts> using type_set = std::variant<tag_t<Ts>...>;

using my_types = type_set<int, double, char, std::string>;
template <typename T>
constexpr my_types some_constexpr_function() {return tag<T>;}

void do_something()
{
  constexpr my_types n = some_constexpr_function<Example>();
  std::visit( [&]( auto tag ) {
    typename decltype(tag)::type example_object;
  }, n );
}
```

bit crazy, and every type has to be supported by the visit lambda, but...

Comment: You could go full crazy and hash the [type's name as a string](https://github.com/Sinacam/typestring).

Comment: @PasserBy that's what I do with `some_constexpr_function`.
I don't understand @Yakk-AdamNevraumont 's answer but that's because of my lack of knowledge, I still need a better grasp on std::visit and probably not just that. Thank you for this though, I'm glad to learn more